# Basic Java Program that uses Inheritance is giving me a few puzzling errors

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child

for the past few weeks, I have been working on a program that uses inheritance, and encountered a few bugs along the way. First of all, it is meant to inherit at least twice and so I decided to create a simple car/Toyota class. Here is my code for the base class:

```
    package *********;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Toyota
{
   public String make; // The make of the vehicle

   public int numberOfDoors; // The number of doors of the vehicle

   public boolean startCar; // Is true if the car has been started

   public int speed; // The speed of the vehicle

   static Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

   public Toyota() //Default constructor for initializing default values
   {
       make = "Toyota";
       numberOfDoors = 4;
       startCar = false;
       speed = 45;
   }

   //Parent class methods for user operations
   {
   if (startCar)
                                                   { 
   startCar = false;
   System.out.println("Car is parked and not started");
   System.exit(0);
   }
   else
   {
   startCar = true;
   System.out.println("Car is started");
   }
   }

   public void status() // Method for displaying the status
   {
       System.out.println("Make: "+make + ", number of doors "+
       numberOfDoors + ", speed " + speed);  
   }
     public void increaseSpeed() //Method for setting the channel
   {   
       System.out.println("Keep your foot on the gas.");
   speed = scnr.nextInt();
   System.out.println("The speed has changed to "+speed);
   }
}
```

Here is the error(s) I am getting:

> No applet or method.

Here is the other class that extends the first one:

```
    package ********;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ToyotaCorolla extends Toyota
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // int ch = 0;
      int sp = 0;
       //MyTelevision TV = new MyTelevision(); //Creating object for MyTelevision class
       ToyotaCorolla LE = new ToyotaCorolla();
       //TV.power(); //Calling super class methods with child class object
       LE.start();
           //TV.status();
           LE.status();

   while (sp!=4) //Switch case for user choice
   {  
   System.out.println("Start the car and put your foot on the gas...");
   System.out.println("1; put the foot on the gas...");
   System.out.println("2; increase the speed...");
   System.out.println("3; slow down!");
   System.out.println("4; park the vehicle and stop.");
   sp = scnr.nextInt();

           switch (sp)
           {
   case 1:   
           LE.buildSpeed(); //Calling super class methods with child class object
   break;
   case 2: LE.increaseSpeed();//Calling super class methods with child class object
   break;
   case 3: LE.decreaseSpeed();//Calling super class methods with child class object
   break;
   case 4: LE.start(); //Calling super class methods with child class object
   default: System.out.println("Please input a valid option.");
   break;
   }

       }

   }
   }
```

And the errors...

> Every time "LE" is referenced, it gives me an error, even though I declared it in the first/parent class. I even changed it to lowercase just because and obviously did not make a difference. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: you did not have  'start()','buildSpeed()','increaseSpeed()' methods.

Comment: Your problem seems to be `if (startCar)`  is not inside any method. And you are calling methods you don't have implemented

Comment: The methods `buildSpeed`, `start` and `decreaseSpeed` are missing.

Comment: Other than the missing methods I don't see a problem. Are your classes in the same package?

Comment: @modus Hello, and yes, my classes are all in the package, which is my last name(which is why I crossed it out.) I will add them, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define these methods in your `Toyota` `class` ,it will run fine + rename your `package` name which will not give any compile time error .example ->

```
package mypack;



   public void start()
    {
   //TODO code
   }
   public void  buildSpeed()
    {
    //TODO code
    }
   public void decreaseSpeed()
    {
    //TODO code
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I am still having the "no applet or method" error on "Toyota" and here is what it says:
>javac: invalid flag: ToyotaCorolla.class
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

and on "ToyotaCorolla", I am getting the same error with "LE" and the first error says it cannot find the symbol for >ToyotaCorolla extends Toyota

Comment: you are packages,did you compile it package credentials ? I have executed this on my machine its running fine.

Comment: I ill test it further, thanks!